# Including firebase 5 in Angular 6 application without using AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase

I am receiving errors when I am attempting to include  firebase into my Angular application (I do not wish to use AngularFire2)

// app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from'firebase/dist/index.esm.js';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';

import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, Event as NavigationEvent } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSya8liEExAoc3jmGhokAk",
      authDomain: "firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://hellodate.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "hellodate-a0be3",
      storageBucket: "hellodate-a0be3.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "6120921"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

  }
}
```

In the browser I am receiving the following error:

```
FirebaseError {code: "app/no-app", message: "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been cre…- call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' h….module.ts (http://localhost:4200/main.js:213:77)"}
code
:
"app/no-app"
message
:
"Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)."
name
:
"[DEFAULT]"
stack
:
"[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).↵    at error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59708:21)↵    at app (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59591:13)↵    at Object.serviceNamespace [as firestore] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59649:47)↵    at Object../src/app/shared/myfire.service.ts (http://localhost:4200/main.js:935:60)↵    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:77:30)↵    at 
:
Error
```

How do I include raw firebase library without use of angularFire in my Angular application ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm install firebase --save` ?
If not, then do so.

Or, Did you use auto import statement for firebase?

If yes, try to change import:

`import firebase from'firebase/dist/index.esm.js';`

to

`import firebase from "firebase";`

Comment: yes .. ofcourse .. firebase is installed .. and import firebase from 'firebase' doesn't work with firebase v 5.x

Comment: how about  `import firebase from "firebase/app";`